# mysqli insert keep giving error

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

I am trying to insert data into this table and I keep getting this error: Unknown column 'question2' in 'field list'

I have double checked and question2 column is part of the table. What in the code is wrong?

```
$q = mysqli_query ($dbc, 
    "INSERT INTO t_pornography (member_id, question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8, question9, question10, question11, question12, question13, question14, question15, question16, question17, question18, question19, question20) 
     VALUES ('$member_id', '$question1', '$question2', '$question3', '$question4', '$question5', '$question6', '$question7', '$question8',  '$question9',  '$question10',  '$question11',  '$question12',  '$question13',  '$question14',  '$question15', '$question16',  '$question17', '$question18', '$question19',  '$question20')"
);
```

Comment: does your T_pronography table contain 'question2'?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to insert data into this table and I keep getting this error: Unknown column 'question2' in 'field list'

It's not, it's highly unlikely that the database is lying to you. My database never lies to me. The field 'question2' simply doesn't exist in the table 't_pornography'. You can check this by executing a simple select query:

```
$q = 'SELECT question2 FROM t_pornography';
```

That will surely give you the same error. Also, while you're at it, read up on [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Having fields with the same name appended with a number generally is a sign that you're making a mistake.

Comment: Thanks. There was a space on the left side of the column

Answer (score 0):

Got it, column was not trimmed, had space that needed removal